# How to set header key in select tag in struts2

Tags: struts2

I am implementing struts2 select tag using map as shown below

```
 <s:select list="myMap" 
           name="myName"  
           headerKey="?"//Here I want to set all the keys in myMap as  HeaderKey
           headerValue="--Select--"
     />
```

In my header Value .. I want to send all the Keys in `myMap` as key to the action class.

I have tried all the expressions but that is taking as String .. Is it possible to send like that please Help

Comment: Better do it in the action. Send some special string (e.g. empty string) from the jsp and in the action check if `myName` equals that special string get all keys from the map.

Comment: Ya did the same thing .. But would like to know if anything at JSP level.. Thank you